# Prove the existence of an epsilon neighborhood for a function continuous at a point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Assume that a function $f\colon D \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at point $a$ and $f(a) > 0$. Show that there is an epsilon-neighborhood such that $f(x) > 0$ $\forall x \in (a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon)$.

I use the epsilon-delta definition of continuity and get $0<\frac{f(a)}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3f(a)}{2}$. However, I am confused how to get to the epsilon-neighborhood.

Editions

Definition of coninuity

$\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0 \colon\forall x\in D$ $|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$

What I do is I fix an epsilon such that $\epsilon= \frac{f(a)}{2} > 0$. Then $ |f(x) - f(a)| < \frac{f(a)}{2} \iff \frac{-f(a)}{2} + f(a)< f(x) < \frac{f(a)}{2} + f(a) \implies 0<\frac{f(a)}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3f(a)}{2}$

I know that it looks like I found the neighborhood. However, I am not sure how to show that using the function domain values.

Comment: It seems to me that what you found _is_ an epsilon neighborhood. But it would be easier to discuss this is you gave more details about what you did. Exactly how does the epsilon-delta definition of continuity get $0<\frac{f(a)}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3f(a)}{2}$? Please **edit the question** to show how you got that far, and don't leave out any of the steps you took to get there.

Comment: You are already there. For $\varepsilon =\tfrac{f(a)}{2}$, there exists a  $\delta >0$, such that for every $x\in (a-\delta, a+\delta)$, $f(x)\in \Big(\tfrac{f(a)}{2}, \tfrac{3f(a)}{2}\Big)$.

Comment: Looks like you are there... $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0\cdots$ Let  $\epsilon = \frac {f(a)}{2}, a-\delta <x<a+\delta \implies 0<\frac {f(a)}{2}<f(x)<\frac {3f(a)}{2}$

Comment: In your question, $\epsilon$ takes the rule of $\delta$ and vice versa. 
Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

For $\delta = \dfrac{f(a)}{2} $ you have $\epsilon \gt 0 $ such that for each 
$x \in [a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon]$ $|f(x)-f(a)| < \delta $

You just "swapped" $\epsilon $ and $\delta $  in the formal definition.